# What are the origins of Vorcan Radok?

Tags: malazan, steven-erikson

Given the fact that Vorcan Radok is Mistress of the Assassins' Guild I would assume that there would be some explanation as to where did she come from. Is there more Vorcan Radok's character expansion?

Comment: I assume she is a native of Darujhistan. Any particular reason to assume otherwise? Also, her daughter features in Esselmont's books, so some details might be there.

Comment: I know that Assassins Guild is based in Darujhistan, hence the possible assumption that she comes from there. What I'm looking for is if Erikson explained somewhere in text where did she come from, who were her parents or alike information about her.

Comment: I remember somewhere in one of the books (8 or 9 I think, so spoilers) when Rallick Nom escapes the Finnest House, Raest says she is a demon? Or was it one of the Ascendants that tell Baruk something about her? I cannot remember the specifics, but seem to think that there's something more to her.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there more Vorcan Radok's character expansion?

No, as of now all that's known is that she was in the cabal with Baruk and Mistress of the Assassin's Guild.  She seems like a likely candidate to get some exposition in the Encyclopedia Malaz though.

Answer (score 0):

There are definitely details in Esselmonts books. Nothing too revealing yet, but you do learn about he Cabal, Vorcan, and her daughter (although maybe not *exactly* what they are, in a way), which is part of Darujhistan's ancient history, although not as far back as Raest, I believe. Man, I gotta go re-read those books again in time for E's new novel to come out..

Answer (score -1):

Vorcan is a demon, summoned by the Tyrant of Darujhistan she is part of the cabal of 12 other demons, Baruk is one of the other demons, so is Mamut, Cutter's "uncle", they try to prevent the tyrant from returning because they don't want to be re-inslaved

Comment: Do you have any sources you can cite to support your assertions?